# Return True If Contains in String in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How do i return `true` if `location.pathname` is found in of these strings is found in ES6?

```
  const noActionMenuRoutes = [
    '/master/employees',
    '/employees/dashboard',
    '/employees/requests',
    '/projects/myprojects',
  ];

  const noActionMenus = () => {
    if (location.pathname.some(noActionMenuRoutes)) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Did you try indexOf() ?

Comment: `noActionMenuRoutes .some(x => location.pathname.includes(x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript array `includes` or `indexOf` function.

```js
if (noActionMenuRoutes.some(route => location.pathname.includes(route)))
```

```js
if (noActionMenuRoutes.some(route => location.pathname.indexOf(route) !== -1)
```

Comment: Sorry for the downvote but the question is only partially answered. The OP wants to check if any of the items include the pathname not if one of the items is the pathname.

Comment: Ah, I see... Updated answer.

Comment: Revoked downvote. I'm still not really clear whether it's the pathname including the route or the route including the pathname

Answer (score 2):

Use findIndex

```js
return noActionMenuRoutes.findIndex(el => el.includes(location.pathname)) != -1;
```

Comment: Is this the most efficient way and the best performance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.includes()` to determines whether one string may be found within another string.

As `noActionMenuRoutes` is an array iterate over it and validate against each string

```
const noActionMenus = () => {
    return noActionMenuRoutes.some(x => location.pathname.includes(x))
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const noActionMenuRoutes = [
    '/master/employees',
    '/employees/dashboard',
    '/employees/requests',
    '/projects/myprojects',
  ];

const noActionMenus = () => noActionMenuRoutes.some(path => location.pathname.includes(path));

console.log(noActionMenus() )
```

Comment: Tip: just return the boolean value of some, no need to use if statements.